# How do I subclass UITextField and override drawPlaceholderInRect to change Placeholder color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, subclass

I have a 3 `UITextField` with placeholder text set. On one of the `UITextField` I want the placeholder text to be red.

Now after googling it seems the best way to do this is to subclass UITextField and override `drawPlaceholderInRect`.

How do I go about subclassing and overriding `drawPlaceholderInRect`? I've not found any code examples or tutorials on this and I'm new to objective-c and iOS development so finding it tricky to work it out.

**Answer:**

Created a new objective-c class called `CustomUITextFieldPlaceholder` which subclassed `UITextField`. In `CustomUITextFieldPlaceholder.m` put the following code

```
 @implementation CustomUITextFieldPlaceholder

- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Set colour and font size of placeholder text
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
}

@end
```

To implement the above in your project

```
#import "CustomUITextFieldPlaceholder.h"
```

and

```
IBOutlet CustomUITextFieldPlaceHolder *txtName;
```

**Note: This works and I believe is correct practice, however I have not fully tested it. Hope this example helps others in my situation.**

**Edit:**

Changed

```
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
```

for

```
[[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7] setFill];
```

So that I could set the opacity to 70% to mimic default placeholder.

Comment: Subclassing and overriding that method won't help you change the font colour, it just lets you customise where the placeholder is displayed.

Comment: maybe you can try overriding this delegate method - `(void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer you specific question, this is how subclassing works:

```
// CustomTextField.h
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField {
}
@end
```

Here's how to override the method:

```
@implementation
- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
}
@end
```

However I don't think that's the method you want to override. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
@implementation
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Your drawing code.
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Erik, your right i did mean drawPlaceholderInRect. I will have a go at creating the code to do this, fingers crossed :)

Comment: but after creating class and adding this method in implementation i cant got change on my textfield placeholder color

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourTextfield setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:62.0/255.0f green:62.0/255.0f blue:62./255.0f alpha:1.0f]  forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

I guess this would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing won't change the color. I have put forward a work around here.

[UITextField placeholder font color white iOS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496114/uitextfield-placeholder-font-color-white-ios-5/15992570#15992570)