# UITextField placeholder font color white iOS 5?

Tags: ios5, interface-builder, uitextfield, xcode4.3, placeholder

I have a problem in a XIB. The color of my placeholder color is default gray in interface builder but when i run the app the color of the text i white, and I'cant see it because the background is white.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override `drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect` as such to manually render the placeholder text in `UITextField`

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
}
```

Comment: When you override, does that mean you have to create a subclass of `UITextField`? Say, for instance, `CustomTextField`?

Comment: I have this error: <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0 
pls tell me how i can fix it?

Comment: [activeView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

Answer (score 1):

The above solution did not work for me, I used the following workaround.

```
[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITextField class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

But then I got to know another bug, the above did the job but it also reset the color of all other labels to Default Black. Then I had to sub class the UILabel class and use my class in all other labels in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix on the syntax:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITextField class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```