# Centering Placeholder Text in Subclass of UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4, uitextfield

So first, I needed to set the placeholder text color, so I subclassed the UITextfield as shown in several stack overflow posts. This works fine. Here is an example post of this: [How do I subclass UITextField and override drawPlaceholderInRect to change Placeholder color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151474/how-do-i-subclass-uitextfield-and-override-drawplaceholderinrect-to-change-place).

But, when I try to use `searchNameField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;` It is no longer centering the placeholder. The input text is still centered fine.

So then, assuming that the centering is not working because of the subclassing, what do I have to add to my UITextField subclass in order to have the placeholder text centered?

Thanks

**Edit**

Here is the code I used to solve this problem. This is placed inside my subclass of UITextField.

```
- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds 
{
    CGSize size = [[self placeholder] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:placeholdTextSize]];

    return CGRectMake( (bounds.size.width - size.width)/2 , bounds.origin.y , bounds.size.width , bounds.size.height);
}
```

Note that placeholdTextSize is a property that I set during initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go buddy

subclassing UITextField will do the work:

```
// CustomTextField.h
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField {
}
@end
```

override the methods:

```
@implementation
- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);//Return your desired x,y position and width,height
}

- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //draw place holder.
 [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];

}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you. For completeness: to solve this problem, I used the 'placeholderRectForBounds' method. My edit in the original question shows the code for anyone that is interested.

Answer (score 4):

i think this will work (tested)

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {

      [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
      [self.placeholder drawInRect:rect
                          withFont:self.font
                     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation
                         alignment:self.textAlignment];
    }
```

https://github.com/mschulkind/cordova-true-native-ios/blob/master/Classes/UITextFieldPlugin.m

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in UITextfield subclass

```
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {

[[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.8] setFill];

[[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

}