# UITextField placeholder shifts when subclassed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, subclass, placeholder

I am using a subclassed `UITextField` to use a custom font. When I set a placeholder for that `textfield` it gets shifted up a little, but the when I start entering the text, the `frame` of text has no problem. Is there a way to fix the placeholder shifting issue.

Comment: See these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539404/centering-placeholder-text-in-subclass-of-uitextfield

Answer (score 1):

```
self.txtFirstName.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
self.txtFirstName.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
self.txtFirstName.placeholder = @"Enter First Name here";
self.txtFirstName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I tried `setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter` which solved my issue.

```
            UITextField *txtPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,55, 255, 25)];
            [txtPassword setPlaceholder:@"Password..."];
            [txtPassword setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [txtPassword setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]];
            [txtPassword setSecureTextEntry:YES];
            [txtPassword setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
            [txtPassword setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
            [txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];
```

Hope this helps.